# Geoshow function matlab error

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use geoshow in matlab to plot a lat lon coordinate, for example

```
geoshow(-75.30355274,-87.96741337) 
Undefined function 'geoshow' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

I have also tried using   geoshow([-75.30355274],[-87.96741337]) but I still get the error. does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: The sintax is right. `geoshow` is part of `Mapping Toolbox`. Perhaps you don't have it installed?

Comment: Type `ver map` at the command line to check if you have the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is very probably a problem with the path of the function file.

One easy way to verify this is to open your function in the Editor and try to execute it. This would make the Editor try to run the file, and in case the file is not in path, it will prompt you with a message box. Choose Add to Path in that, and you must be fine to go.

Also as mentioned in one of the comment to your question please verify if the Mapping toolbox is installed or not.....